# How can I tell which probability is used in the numerator of the odds ratio of this logistic regression output in R?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, r-caret

I'm very familiar with the math behind logistic regression, but I don't know which probability is in the numerator of odds ratio, according to the `R` output.

Consider the following:

```
library(dplyr)
library(caret)

set.seed(42)

levels(iris$Species) <- list("setosa" = c("setosa"), "not_setosa" = c("versicolor", "virginica"))
train <- sample.int(0.5*nrow(iris))
test <- setdiff((1:nrow(iris)), train)
m <- train(factor(Species) ~ .,
           data = iris %>% slice(train),
           method = "regLogistic",
           trControl = trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                                    number = 10,
                                    repeats = 3),
           tuneGrid = expand.grid(.cost = 1,
                                  .loss = c("L1", "L2_dual", "L2_primal"),
                                  .epsilon = seq(0.001, 0.01, length.out = 5)),
           metric = "Accuracy",
           preProcess = c("center", "scale"))
```

Here is the model output:

```
> m$finalModel$W
     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width       Bias
[1,]            0  -0.1032026     3.580843   0.9182011 -0.6719641
```

So I have:

log(P/(1-P)) = that regression model above + Bias

However, I'm not sure if P corresponds to the probability of `setosa` or `not_setosa`. How can I tell which one it is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

P is the probability of the second factor level.

From `?binomial`:

> For the binomial and quasibinomial families the response can be specified in one of three ways:
>
> 1. As a factor: ‘success’ is interpreted as the factor not having the first level (and hence usually of having the second level).
>
> ...

Since you set your levels to be "setosa" fist and "not_setosa" second, P is the probability of "not_setosa".